# Inline SVG + jQuery - Mouse events not detected in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom, svg

I have an HTML5 document with some inline SVG.

I am trying to detect mousedown and mouseup events on a specific element using jQuery.

```
$( "#rectangle" ).mousedown(function() {
        console.log("MOUSEDOWN");
    });

    `
```

This works in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.

I've tried detecting mousedown on the main svg element itself:

```
$( "#mysvg" ).mousedown(function() {
        console.log("MOUSEDOWN");
});
```

...and this works fine in all browsers.

So, apparently, FF is not detecting mouse events within the SVG.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: try using a namespaced selector, like `$("svg:#rectangle")` or `$("svg\\:#rectangle")`.

Comment: Can you create a complete testcase e.g. a jsfiddle?

Comment: I use the same logic - it works in all browsers - you are prob. searching in the wrong place;

Comment: 2. comment: sometimes, FF just needs a restart when things dont work any more, I spent much time searching for an error, and a FF restart solved it, this sometimes happens to me after heavily using debugger in FF and so on